# Show that $\frac{1}{1.a} \gt 1-0.a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose the selling price of an item is $100$.
Increasing it by $25\%$ makes it $125$

Next, to get back to its original price *we cannot simply do* $0.75*1.25$.
(Yeah we must do $\frac{1}{1.25}*125$)

Easy to see $\dfrac{1}{1.25} \gt 1-0.25$ because $25\%$ of $125$ is obviously greater than $25\%$ of $100$.

This makes me wonder if this is true in general.. and how to convince myself more strongly of this?

---

My work:
First I increase $x$ by $25\%$
$1.25x = x + 0.25x$

Next if I decrease this new result by $25\%$
$(1-0.25)*1.25x = (1-0.25)*(1+0.25)x =(1^2-0.25^2)x = x - 0.25^2x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by $1.a$ you mean a real that has $a$ as a decimal expansion, it is false.  You are claiming $\frac 1{1+a} \gt a$ where $a \in [0,1)$  That will be false when $a(1+a) \gt 1$ or when $a \gt \frac {-1+\sqrt 5}2\approx 0.618$

What you are trying to say is $(1+a)(1-a) \lt 1$ which is true because $(1+a)(1-a)=1-a^2 \lt 1$

Comment: oh right $(1+a)(1-a) = 1-a^2\lt 1$ does the trick! Ty :) I made a typo in my question, extremely sorry. I actually wanted to show this:

$$\frac{1}{1.a} \gt 1-0.a$$

Comment: Yes, that claim is true as we both show.